# Filtering out rows where two columns equal one thing

Tags: php, mysql, sql, laravel

I have the following query. I'd like for it to filter out rows after the join where both type and relationship equal 'communicator'. I tried `whereRaw('(type <> communicator and relationship <> communicator')` but I just get a nasty error. How can I achieve the result I'm looking for?

Relationship is in `titles_to_communicators` and type is in `communicators`.

```
$query = \DB::table('titles_to_communicators')
    ->leftJoin('communicators', 'communicators.id', '=', 'titles_to_communicators.communicator_id')
    ->where('relationship', '<>', 'character')
    ->whereIn('title_id', $childIds)
    ->groupBy('communicators.slug')
    ->limit(40);
```

Comment: What is the structure of these two tables, what are the relations between them and what error do you get?

Comment: Your attempt is missing a closing paren inside the quote

Answer (score 1, accepted):

try

> where (type = "communicator" and relation = "communicator")

Comment: Seriously is this js or php?

Comment: I mean in PHP is would need double quotes the way laravel needs it but he's still right...